# How can I get NSTimer to continue while adjusting timeInterval - iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer

I have a knob `IBAction` that adjusts the `timeInterval` of an `NSTimer`.

But I can't find a way to get the timer to continuously fire while adjusting the `timeInterval`. I guess this is because I am continuously invalidating and re-instancing the timer, right?

Is there a way to get it to work smoothly - so that the timer will accelerate/decelerate with the knob motions?

```
-(IBAction)autoSpeed:(UISlider *)sender
{
    timeInterval = (60/sender.value) / 4;

    if (seqState){
        [self changeTempo];
    }

    [self displayBPM:[sender value]:[sender isTouchInside]];
}

-(void) changeTempo
{
    if (repeatingTimer!= nil) {
        [repeatingTimer invalidate];
        repeatingTimer = nil;
        repeatingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: timeInterval target:self selector:@selector(changeAutoSpeedLed) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    }
    else
        repeatingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: timeInterval target:self selector:@selector(changeAutoSpeedLed) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer, I hope it helps

Comment: Did my updated answer help you at all?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try it yet. but will soon and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You can recreate the timer in the tick.

---

### .h file

You have to make a property called interval.

```
@property NSTimeInterval interval;
```

---

### .m file

First, initialise it:

```
self.interval = 100;
[self timerTick];
```

Then you can use the `timerTick` method to recreate the timer if

```
- (void)timerTick {
    if (self.interval) {
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:self.interval target:self selector:@selector(timerTick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        self.interval = 0;
    }


    // Do all the other stuff in the timer
}
```

Then you can set `self.interval` whenever you want and the timer will automatically be recreated.

Comment: doesn't timeInterval just return? I don't think you can set it like that, can you?

Comment: `fire` doesn't start the timer, it actually causes the target to call the selector. To start the timer you need to add to to a runloop, e.g. `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:repeatingTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];`

Comment: @frankie Yes you can, `timeInterval` is a property. This is called dot-notation. Check out this here: http://blog.bignerdranch.com/83-83/

Comment: I understand but I am getting an error - `no setter method setTimeInterval for assignment to property`.

Comment: timeInterval is read-only; you cannot set it using the code in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that it's not running smoothly is because you're using `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`, which, according to Apple's documentation:

> Creates and returns a new NSTimer object and schedules it on the current run loop in the default mode.

The default mode is blocked by UI interaction, so if you're controlling the knob the timer is blocked. If you instead use code such as:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:repeatingTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

then the code will not be blocked by UI.

Comment: thanks. i will invoke this anyway although i dont think its the problem as doing other UI actions doesn't seem to affect the timer.